# Почему я не могу печатать в input

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("netab");
 x[n].style.display = 'block';
 if (n == 0) {
  document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
 } else {
  document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
 }
 if (n == (x.length-1)) {
  document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
 } else {
  document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
 }
 fixStepIndicator(n);
}

function nextPrev(n) {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("netab");
 if (n == 1 && !validationForm()) return false;
 x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
 currentTab = currentTab + n;
 if (currentTab >= x.length) {
  document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
  return false;
 }
 showTab(currentTab);
}

function validationForm() {
 var i, x, y, valid = true;
 x = document.getElementsByClassName("netab");
 y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName('input');
 for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  if (y[i].value == "") {
   y[i].className += " invalid";
   valid = false;
  }
 }
  if (valid) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
 return valid;
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" activeon", "");
 }
 x[n].className += " activeon";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Risque');

#regForm {
  background-color: darkred;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#regForm > h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.netab {
  padding: 20px 60px 20px 40px;
  display: none;
}

.netab p > input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
}

#prevBtn, #nextBtn {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#prevBtn:hover, #nextBtn:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.netab p > input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.step.activeon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
  <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
   <h1>Register:</h1>
   <div class="netab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.value = ''" name="name" type="text"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.value = ''" name="surname" type="text"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="netab">Contact Info:
       <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" type="text"></p>
       <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone" type="text"></p>
      </div>
   <div class="netab">Birthday:
       <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd" type="text"></p>
       <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn" type="text"></p>
       <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy" type="text"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="netab">Login Info:
       <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname" type="text"></p>
       <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
   </div>
   <div style="overflow:auto;">
       <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
       <span class="step"></span>
       <span class="step"></span>
       <span class="step"></span>
       <span class="step"></span>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Быть может потому что `oninput="this.className = ''"`? Ну или все же `oninput="this.value = ''"`

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил тогда.